# What do i need to explicitly deallocate in jMagick

Tags: imagemagick, jmagick

I'm using jMagick to do some basic image manipulation.  I know ImageMagick is written in C, so I was wondering which methods need to be invoked and when to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: use there documentation

Comment: If you can find documentation on this, you're a better person than I.  Also "their", not "there"

Comment: That why I became a programmer and not an english teacher, because I don't care so "They're" you have it - http://www.jmagick.org/jmagick-doc/

Comment: Yes, I've seen that.  I don't see anything in there explaining when it's important to explicitly free resources.  I know MagickImage has a destroy() method, but no indication as to when you're supposed to use it.